# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 58: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, spyder

Suddenly I can't run scripts in spyder 2.7. And en error always shows up.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 58: ordinal not in range(128)

And in stackoverflow there are many solutions to that. But when I try the method

```
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

it gives another error.

> LookupError: unknown encoding: cp0

And I restart spyder, the second error is gone but the first exists always.

Any idea for that? It's very strange because it's just suddenly that I can't use spyder any more.

Comment: Have you tried adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your script?

Comment: Does your working directory contain any unusal characters? I had this error on a german localisation, when spyder wanted to load filed from my desktop, which was called "Arbeitsfläche". Spyder didn't like the 'ä'.

Comment: Yes, # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- is added at first line of a script automatically in Spyder. There is certainly no unusal characters. As mentioned, the same script can be run before. But suddenly it can't be run. :(

Comment: Is this error coming in Bokeh?, as that may be due to issues with Bokeh source file readers.

Comment: HI, Aritesh. I'm afraid not the error is because of Bokeh. I didn't know this library before. Do you know how to check it's caused by bokeh or not?

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?